# Which should I get a FAA glider licence or a Canadian glider licence?

Tags: faa, glider, transport-canada

I plan to operate in the Caribbean (Antigua, under ECCAA jurisdiction, which does not have a glider rating of its own) and not in the USA or Canada. I am looking at which one would be require less work and time on my side. I plan to give rides in my country and practice the sport.

Comment: The Caribbean includes multiple jurisdictions/countries that may have their own aviation regulations on certificates they accept from out of country. Can you specify (country/jurisdiction) where you intend on operating.

Comment: The problem with my country (antigua and barbuda ) ECCAA is that they do not have any glider exams or glider clubs or schools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is heavily dependent on the local jurisdictions you plan to operate in and what their laws are.

First off you must find out if your desired countries of operation accept foreign certificates. This varies heavily all over the world and can range from full no questions asked acceptance, to you needing to simply take the test again (in that country) through any various case you can think of.

Second you need to find out what certificate you need. Here in the US to give rides (and receive compensation for such) you need a commercial certificate. This looks like it [extends to gliders as well](http://www.ssa.org/GliderPilotRatings).

Hours.

The FAA requires a few more hours than the Canadian certificate will,

[FAA](http://www.ssa.org/GliderPilotRatings)

> - Are at least 16 years of age; and
> - Have logged at least 10 hours of
>     flight time in a glider and that flight time must include at least 20
>     total glider flights, and
> - Have 2 hours of solo flight time in a
>     glider, and
> - Have passed the FAA written examination; and
> - Have passed the flight exam with a FAA Examiner.

[Canada](http://www.sac.ca/website/index.php/fr/home-all/learning-to-soar)

> - A minimum of 6 hours of flight training under the direction and supervision of an instructor
> - At least 2 hours of solo flight time, including a minimum of 20 takeoffs and 20 landings

Right off the bad Canada requires 4 less hours which, no matter how you spin it will be cheaper (since you have to pay for less time).

Here is the US if you are not a citizen you will need to pass an NTSB background check to train. I do not know if Canada has a similar requirement.

Travel, assuming you are in the Caribbean already it may be cheaper to travel to Florida (or the like) to train then go all the way up to Canada for your training.

Edit:

According to this document the ECCAA does issue glider ratings

> [2.1.2.3 RATINGS ISSUED](http://www.eccaa.aero/images/stories/docs/cars/Part%2002%20-%20Personnel%20Licensing%20A&B%20.pdf)
>
> (a) The Authority may issue the following ratings for pilots
>   (i) Category ratings in the following aircraft:
>
> - (a) Aeroplane;
> - (b) Rotorcraft;
> - (c) Glider;
> - (d) Lighter-than-air;
> - (e) Power lift.

Comment: The problem with the canada one is that the glider license written exam is not public, in terms of questions, while in the usa the questions are public most of them. In the states it is 14 not 16 and they do not require a TSA clearance, for glider.

Comment: They might do but it does not make sense since there is not glider schools in the country but there is a pilot school for aircraft.

Comment: The difference in hours required only matters if you can complete the training within those hours.  If you need a few more hours to learn the material, then the legal minimums will become irrelevant.

Comment: Very true, but there are those that complete in the minimum time so I felt it appropriate to mention. For the record my PPL took well over the 40 required hours.